# HTTP Host header www issue

Tags: http, http-headers, host

I'm working on an http proxy and I'm having an issue with the "Host" header. For certain websites, including "www." before the domain winds up getting me a return 400. On other websites, not including "www." before the domain gives me the same. I tried including multiple "Host" headers, one with "www." and one without, but that was a shot in the dark and didn't work. What is the correct header that will give me a response from both kinds of sites? Below is the command/header I'm sending:

```
GET /{directory of resource} HTTP/1.0
Host: {www.}{domain}
Connection: close
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: There is no "right" or "wrong" header. It is simply two different hosts you send your request to. It is impossible to generally answer here, since the correct answer in each case obviously depends on the configuration of the receiving http server or even on the name resolution.

Comment: When implementing a "proxy" of some kind then you always want to use that host name that has been specified in the original request you are trying to relay. You should _not_ try to alter that information.

Comment: I guess my question then is how does a browser determine which header to send. Adding "www." to these same sites in a browser makes no difference. How does it choose which header to send?

Comment: A browser does not "chose". It first tries as it is told and sends the host name it is given. If that fails then _some_ browsers make a wild guess and put a `www.` before the hostname. Sometimes that works, especially for cheap or badly configured sites. It is questionable if that is a good strategy, since it tries to outsmart the user, which is rarely a good idea. In the end that `www.` is a relict from the 80th when there was still a single system used for each page served. It does not serve any purpose any more and is pretty annoying.

Comment: This also means that, as written above, you should _not_ duplicate that guessing attempt in your proxy, since browsers already play that game. Isn't that enough? If the first attempt fails you can bet you will get a second request from the browser with a prepended `www.`. Then again you send exactly what you were asked.

Comment: Ah, and to make understanding easier: normally, for correctly configured sites, the effect that a `www` is prepended to a domain name is _not_ decided on the client side (the browser), but is only a reaction to a redirection header sent by the server as a reply to the first request.  So it is the _server_ that decides how it wants to be requested.

Comment: Thank you for your informative responses! One more quick thing since you seem pretty knowledgable: "http://" should always be stripped off, right?

Comment: The `http://` is _not_ part of the host header! It is part of the _url_, the url is invalid without a specified scheme. The host header contains the host name, nothing else. Again: you should send the host name you receive, you should not try to make things up on the proxy level between client and server.

Comment: Simply go and use a network sniffer to watch a few example requests and answers by monitoring the communication between your browser and some server. You will learn a lot. Also reading some protocol definitions is something you have to do if you want to implement those protocols.